# Disable/Enable conents of uitableview cell when loading uitable view from other view controller

Tags: ios, tableview, uitableview

I have a tableview controller with navigation bar, it is used for user profile screen. tableview has 10 custom cells containing label,textfields and textview and navigation bar buttons are use for enabling/disabling the editing of tableviewcell contents. A user can load this user profile screen from any controller in the app with a button on that that view controller. what i want to do is, when a user selects to open this user profile screen(tableview Controller) from anywhere, it should appear only viewing mode; its cell having textfields and Textviews should not be editable. However when user navigates through settings screen of app and goes to user profile screen, its cells could be enable or disabled for editing. any suggestions for this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

### Part 1. Preparing your `UITableViewController` class

1. in the **.h**:

   - add... `@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL enableCellSelection;`
     .
2. in the **.m**

   - in the `-initWithStyle:` do...

     ```
     - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
     {
         self = [super initWithStyle:style];
         if (self) {
             enableCellSelection = YES;
         }
         return self;
     }
     ```
   - in the **`-cellForRowAtIndexPath:`** do...

     ```
     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {
     //your normal cell handling code

     [cell setUserInteractionEnabled:(enableCellSelection ? UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue : UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone)];
     return cell;
     }
     ```

---

### Part 2. Showing your `UITableViewController` class

*From any method...*

```
//alloc/init normally
MyTableViewController *tvcObj = [[MyTableViewController alloc] init];

//explicitly disable the cell selection ability 
tvcObj.enableCellSelection = NO;

//display the tableView
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tvcObj animated:YES];
```

---

Basically, we create a property that we set before showing the `tableView` and when the table loads, it will read this property and appropriately set the interaction ability on the entire cell.
*this is the best I could think of*